# Convert string fields to enum fields in Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api, enums, swagger, swashbuckle

We are using Swashbuckle to document our WebAPI project (using Owin) and are trying to modify the generated Swagger file of Swashbuckle.
With the `DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings()` and an enum property like below, we get an expected result:

```
class MyResponseClass {
    public Color color;
}

enum Color {
    LightBlue,
    LightRed,
    DarkBlue,
    DarkRed
}
```

Swagger generated result:

```
"color": {
  "enum": [
    "LightBlue",
    "LightRed",
    "DarkBlue",
    "DarkRed"
  ],
  "type": "string"
},
```

The challenge for us is that we have some properties that are of type `string` but we are actually treating them as `enum` types. For example:

```
class MyResponseClass {
    public string color;
}
```

The only possible values for this property are `dark-blue`, `dark-red`, `light-blue`, `light-red`.

So, we want something like below as the result:

```
"color": {
  "enum": [
    "light-blue",
    "light-red",
    "dark-blue",
    "dark-red"
  ],
  "type": "string"
},
```

We have lots of these properties with different values in different classes. It would be great to have a custom attribute like below to make it generic. I can't figure out how to create such an attribute and use it in Swashbuckle `DocumentFilters` or `OperationFilters`:

```
public MyEndpointResponseClass {

    [StringEnum("booked", "confirmed", "reserved")]
    public string status;

    // Other properties
}

public MyEndpointRequestClass {

    [StringEnum("dark-blue", "dark-red", "light-blue", "light-red")]
    public string color;

    // Other properties
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a custom attribute (StringEnum) use an attribute that swagger already knows about, a little know attribute (I've never used it before):

```
[RegularExpression("^(dark-blue|dark-red|light-blue|light-red)")]
```

That will inject into the parameter.pattern and then we can read it from the IDocumentSchema and transform it into an enum, here is my code:

```
private class StringEnumDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry s, IApiExplorer a)
    {                
        if (swaggerDoc.paths != null)
        {
            foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.paths)
            {
                ProcessOperation(path.Value.get);
                ProcessOperation(path.Value.put);
                ProcessOperation(path.Value.post);
                ProcessOperation(path.Value.delete);
                ProcessOperation(path.Value.options);
                ProcessOperation(path.Value.head);
                ProcessOperation(path.Value.patch);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessOperation(Operation op)
    {
        if (op != null)
        {
            foreach (var param in op.parameters)
            {
                if (param.pattern != null)
                {
                    param.@enum = param.pattern
                        .Replace("^", "")
                        .Replace("(", "")
                        .Replace(")", "")
                        .Split('|');
                }
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Here is a working example:
http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=TestStringEnum#/TestStringEnum/TestStringEnum_Post

And the code behind that is on GitHub:
[TestStringEnumController.cs](https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Controllers/TestStringEnumController.cs)
[SwaggerConfig.cs#L389](https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L389)

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Sound like a workaround. However, you can't teach developers regular expressions for something that is not actually a regular expression. Besides, what if we want to really use regular expressions for the same field? I still hope that it is possible to do so with a custom attribute...

Comment: On my tests I could not achieve it with a custom attribute (without modifying the core swashbuckle code) the problem was that on IDocumentFilter I could not reflect the object to get the custom attributes.

Comment: And on the case you mention of "use Regular Expressions for the same field", that is the proper RegEx for your scenario! _ Can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: That's why I asked the question in SO! ;) I couldn't get the custom attrribute on IDocumentFilter. I was hoping that someone might know how to do that.

Comment: In case of Regular Expressions, my request is not a regular expression. My reqular expression might be to start with "dark-" and end with "-color". So the regular expression says "dark-*-color". But, in my imaginary(!) attribute, I specify the values. It might not be a good example, but I think it is clear that having some "specific" values are different than having a "regular expressions". If I can't get any more help I might as well implement your way. it's not perfect, but at least it works...

Comment: It would also be an acceptable answer: "it is impossible to do so" but I want to make sure that it is really "impossible". Not just because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Looking closely at your question, you mention: "...properties of type string but treating them as enum" that sounds a lot like a RegEx, _ if you want to get attention from more developers to this question start a bounty.