# Document possible values for a string using Swagger/C#?

Tags: c#, xml, swagger, documentation, summary

Is there a way that I can, on the method summary XML, list the possible values for a string parameter and document it on Swagger?

Like, on the method below, the possible values for ***myParam*** are ***Y*** and ***N***, I want to get it to my Swagger documentation.

```
/// <summary>
/// My method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="myParam">String parameter with predefined values.</param>
/// <returns>Something.</returns>
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 200)]
public JsonResult MyMethod(string myParam)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: If you only have a certain set of values, then you should be using a different data type. For example a `bool` in this case, or if you have more values, an `enum`.

Comment: Here's [link](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/213#issuecomment-271185359) on comment in Swashbuckle Github repository.

Comment: I understand that, but I can't change that, I'm just maintaining the code (documenting it).

Comment: Is this Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net or something else?

Comment: See if [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46794642/113116).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way that I can, on the method summary XML, list the
>   possible values for a string parameter and document it on Swagger?

No you cannot do that

However, swagger defines a [description](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/) field which supports [rich formatting](https://swagger.io/specification/#richText), and which you can use to describe your parameters and therefore the allowed values which may be passed in. This will be visible to anyone consumiong the API definition.

Something like:

```
paths:
  /MyMethod/myParam:
    get:
      summary: Gets a user by ID.
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: myParam
          type: string
          required: true
          description: Must be in the form of "X" or "Y"
```